# Exclude products out of stock from pagination

Tags: pagination, prestashop

I managed to hide all products out of stock from products lists, however the pagination still counts them, even though they are not visible. Is there a way to change the pagination.tpl file so it wouldn't count the products out of stock?

Currently my file is like this:

```
<div class="product-count">
    {if ($n*$p) < $nb_products }
      {assign var='productShowing' value=$n*$p}
    {else}
      {assign var='productShowing' value=($n*$p-$nb_products-$n*$p)*-1}
    {/if}
    {if $p==1}
      {assign var='productShowingStart' value=1}
    {else}
      {assign var='productShowingStart' value=$n*$p-$n+1}
    {/if}
    {if $nb_products > 1}
      {l s='Showing %1$d - %2$d of %3$d items' sprintf=[$productShowingStart, $productShowing, $nb_products]}
    {else}
      {l s='Showing %1$d - %2$d of 1 item' sprintf=[$productShowingStart, $productShowing]}
    {/if}
</div>
```

Comment: the tpl is not the right place to change this. there you are only not displaying them. you should override list functions, or create a cron job that deactivates the out of stock products (this one is better for compatibility).

Comment: I don't know how to do a cron job at all

Comment: Are you using layered navigation block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that way you hide product , but product still there.

In PrestaShop you have a General Rule that determinate if product without stock should be shown.

Go to Prefereces/products  then you have to change to "Not" "Show productos not available on the product pages?.